# The first term of a GP is twice its common ratio. Find the sum of the first two terms of the progression if its sum to infinity is 8

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have tried using $s= \frac{a}{1-r}$, which first term $a=2r \implies r= a/2$.

Substituting $r$ into  $s= \frac{a}{1-r}$ so $ s=8$, $r=a/2$.

$\frac{a}{1-a/2} = 8 \implies a = 8-4a $

c.l,t a+4a=8 ..... If help will be needed

Comment: We have $\frac{2r}{1-r}=8$. So $2r=8-8r$, and now you know $r$.  You were nearly finished too, from $a+4a=8$ we get $5a=8$, so $a=\frac{8}{5}$.

Comment: Whatever you've done so far is correct, and the solution is $a = 8/5$. Simply calculate the second term and add them up.